# trying to rename column in phpmyadmin, getting "unknown column" error

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'm trying to rename a column in phpmyadmin. The column is called `DeathDate`. It is a `varchar(11)`.

I click on the "Structure" tab, then the "Change" option by the `DeathDate` field. The "Change" window comes up. I type a name other than `DeathDate` in the "Name" field.

When I click the "Save" button, I get the message:

> 1054 - Unknown column 'Death(line break)Date' in 'tblName'

Anyone know please what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: From the error message, there seems to be a special character in your column name. Try to fix that, and you should be fine.

Comment: When I try to change the field name, I get the error above.

Answer (score 3):

in SQL command write this code

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME CHANGE OLD_COLUMN_NAME NEW_COLUMN_NAME COLUMN_TYPE;
```

where

`TABLE_NAME` is your table name you want make modify within

`OLD_COLUMN_NAME`  is name of column you want change ex (Deathdate)

```
NEW_COLUMN_NAME is name of new column name ex (DDate)

COLUMN_TYPE is column type  ex (date , text  ) whatever your column type
```

Answer (score 0):

`line break` is not a permitted character.

Take a look at the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html) for permitted characters.

If this doesn't work, try using `ALTER`:

```
ALTER TABLE tblName CHANGE DeathDate DDate varchar(11)
```

Comment: It just breaks that way in the feedback. The name of the field that shows up in phpmyadmin is "DeathDate".

Comment: I'm trying to change it to something like "DDate".

Comment: I tried using ALTER, but I can't get it to recognize the existing field name. I tried 'Death Date', 'DeathDate', both without quote marks. But nothing is working. I might have to recreate the whole table...

Comment: @LauraNMS Take a look at this [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248224/mysql-unknown-column-error-when-using-alter-dont-understand-behaviour). It may be of help.

Comment: for those seeking for solution - outputting result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` somewhere in `<pre>` (or displaying that result as text/plain) to see the all the whitespaces may help